# Angular Universal Support with RouterModule - TypeError: ctor is not a constructor

Tags: angular-universal, angular-router

I have an Angular 4 component library ([using this](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular-library-starter)) that I am importing into an Angular Universal application ([using this](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)).  It is working well until I add the RouterModule to the imports in the module.ts of the component library.

I get the following error when I try to build the universal app:

```
TypeError: ctor is not a constructor
at _createClass (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9559:20)
at _createProviderInstance$1 (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9535:26)
at initNgModule (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:9488:28)
at new NgModuleRef_ (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10585:9)
at createNgModuleRef (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10569:12)
at Object.debugCreateNgModuleRef [as createNgModuleRef] (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12854:12)
at NgModuleFactory_.create (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:13862:25)
at /Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4529:61
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:392:26)
at Object.onInvoke (/Users/mp945gl/Documents/sampleRcl/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:3922:33)
```

I am using angular 4.4.6 in both libraries